# Can't access WSL via IP but via localhost

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Issue: WSL is accessible via http://localhost but not via IP (eg. 127.0.0.1 or the IP supplied by `wsl hostname -i`)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:
Edit the Windows Hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`) and add an alias to it binding the alias to ::1.
For example

```
::1 phpmyadmin.local
```